# Ng-repeat does not updated immediately after getting new data inside wix appication

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create my first application to wix app market using angular js. I have a problem with ng repeat issue. I start my application with empty array. I load an images from wix media gallery to my array, expect the view to be updated. But it does not happen until I use a dummy function inside my viewer. I don't understand why ng-repeat not updated immediately after the images load.

Please help.

Thanks,

Viewer:

```
<div>
<accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
        <accordion-heading>
            Gallery Options <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
        </accordion-heading>

        <div class="gallery-controller">
            <button ng-click="openMediaDialog()" class="uilib-btn opt-add-images-button">Add Images</button>

            <div class="action-button-group">
                <button class="uilib-btn btn-secondary opt-navigation-button">
                    <div class="opt-move-down">
                        <div class="opt-dwon-triangle"></div>
                        <div class="opt-underline"></div>
                    </div>
                </button>

                <button class="uilib-btn btn-secondary opt-navigation-button">
                    <div class="opt-move-down">
                        <div class="opt-dwon-triangle"></div>
                    </div>
                </button>

                <button class="uilib-btn btn-secondary opt-navigation-button">
                    <div class="opt-move-down">
                        <div class="opt-up-triangle"></div>
                    </div>
                </button>

                <button class="uilib-btn btn-secondary opt-navigation-button">
                    <div class="opt-move-down">
                        <div class="opt-underline"></div>
                        <div class="opt-up-triangle"></div>
                    </div>
                </button>

                <button ng-click="debugThis()" class="uilib-btn btn-secondary opt-remove-button-container"> //dummy function
                    <div class="opt-remove-bucket"></div>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="opt-gallery-thumbnail-container">
                <div class="box" wix-scroll="{height:150}">
                    <ul class="opt-gallery-thumbnail">
                        <li ng-repeat="option in galleryThumbnails">
                            <div>
                                <img src="data:image/jpeg; base64, {{option.relativeUri}}">
                                <p ng-model="option.fileName"></p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group is-open="status.open">
        <accordion-heading>
            Gallery Style <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
        </accordion-heading>
        <p>The body of the accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group is-open="status.open">
        <accordion-heading>
            Gallery Other Option <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
        </accordion-heading>
        This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('angularClientApp')
.controller('optionsController', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        //variables
        $scope.galleryThumbnails = [];

        //initialize wix ui
        Wix.UI.initialize({});

        $scope.openMediaDialog = function(){
            var imageUrl = Wix.Settings.openMediaDialog(Wix.Settings.MediaType.IMAGE, true, updateGalleryThumbnail);
        }


        //private functions
        function updateGalleryThumbnail(data){
            setGalleryThumbnails(data);
            console.log($scope.galleryThumbnails)
        }

        function setGalleryThumbnails(data){
            $scope.galleryThumbnails = data;
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Try it after clearing all data of browser.

Comment: Try adding a $scope.$apply() as the last line in your setGallery function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is that your 'galleryThumbnails' should be an attribute of an object, not the object itself, see the example here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

So you could try (not tested):

```
$scope.gallery = {};
$scope.gallery.thumbnails = [];
```

...

```
function setGalleryThumbnails(data){
   $scope.gallery.thumbnails = data;
}
```

and adjust your markup to use this:

```
<li ng-repeat="option in gallery.thumbnails">
```

etc.